# Place div according to Google Maps latitude and longitude

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps

Instead of the Infowindow from Google Maps I wanted to show a div when I click at my marker.
I've got all working good, when I click in marker the div is showed up, the only problem is the position  of div !

My website is responsive so as the map, but the div isn't.
So what I wanted to accomplish is make the position of the div based on latitude and longitude of map, that way, when the map was resized the div will appears at the same place.

I'm noobie so I don't know what to do ...
Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the InfoBox library plugin, it allows you to place your marker at a specified lat/long coordinate. When you click the marker, you can show a content box. It also allows you to use an offset in pixels from that coordinate, so you can move the box in relation to the marker.

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.5/src/infobox.js

Below, in markerOptions, there is a content property that allows you to put in any html. I have an object with many markers, so I'm using a `for` statement here and storing marker and markerOptions in arrays.

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             map: map,
             draggable: false,
             position: new google.maps.LatLng(parksMarkerInfo[r].coordinates[0], parksMarkerInfo[r].coordinates[1]),
             visible: true,
             icon: "http://www.travelalaska.com/~/media/Images/Travel%20Alaska/Maps/Parks/park-marker.png",
            });

          markerOptions = {
             content: "<a href='http://"+window.location.host+"/Destinations/Parks%20and%20Public%20Lands/"+ (parksMarkerInfo[r].markerLink || parksMarkerInfo[r].markerLabel) +".aspx'>"+parksMarkerInfo[r].markerTranslation+"</a>"
            ,disableAutoPan: true
            ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(parksMarkerInfo[r].offset[0], parksMarkerInfo[r].offset[1])
            ,boxStyle: {
              textAlign: "left"
              ,fontSize: "12px"
              ,whiteSpace: "nowrap"
              ,lineHeight: "16px"
              ,fontWeight: "bold"
              ,fontFamily: "Tahoma"
             }
            ,isHidden: false
            ,closeBoxURL: ""
            ,position: new google.maps.LatLng(parksMarkerInfo[r].coordinates[0], parksMarkerInfo[r].coordinates[1])
            ,pane: "floatPane"
            ,enableEventPropagation: false
            ,boxClass: "parkLabel"
          };

          parkMarker.push(marker);
          parkOptions.push(markerOptions);

          parkMarker[arrayLoc].infobox = new InfoBox(parkOptions[arrayLoc]);

          parkMarker[arrayLoc].infobox.open(map, marker);
          parkMarker[arrayLoc].infobox.close();

          google.maps.event.addListener(parkMarker[arrayLoc], 'click', (function(marker, arrayLoc){
            return function(){
                for ( h = 0; h < parkMarker.length; h++ ) {
                    if(parkMarker[h].infobox){
                      parkMarker[h].infobox.close();
                    }
                }
                marker.infobox.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(parkMarker[arrayLoc], arrayLoc));
```

Comment: I'm using Jquery Map Marker Plugin and I can place my marker wherever I want by lat/long. I wanna try to place the div first, instead of using another plugin, but if I cant solve it i'll try waht you said :)

Comment: Does it allow you to place content with the marker? Can you post your code in your question?

Comment: Yes, it allows me to create a infowindow and style her with html and css, but the infowindow is positioned at top. I can post my code but will not help since what I've got is a div in html code

Comment: I don't think that plugin will work for what you want it to do. You would have much more flexibility by using InfoBox, which gives you a div with a class, so you can style it anyway you want and insert any html. The plugin you are using doesn't have a class on the main div you are looking to work with, so it'll be struggle to do much without using some crazy css to access it. If you need any help, feel free to move this to chat, and I'd be happy to give you a hand.

Comment: I will try it, then if I have any problem I ask you for help. thanks :)

Comment: I found and tried this http://jsfiddle.net/jEhJ3/597/ but in my case, when I click in the marker I get an error in console "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<InfoBox> has no method 'open' "

Comment: Did you include the infobox source file? `<script src="infobox link from above"></script>`

Comment: I've got all plugins in a file named "plugins.js" but I've already create another file just with this plugin and still the same error

Comment: It's working ! Have to call it after google maps, my bad ! Today I don't have more time to do work with this, maybe tomorow I've got some new issues. Thanks for all help :)

Comment: Well I think I'm pretty close of what I want to do, thank you for the help :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41950/discussion-between-user2747509-and-brouxhaha)

Answer (score 0):

Can you look at your mouse position instead of the longitude latitude ?
Then on the $window.resize, you can reposition the div as you wish.

```
  $('#your-gmap-div').click(function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var mouseposition = {
        x: e.clientX - offset.left,
        y: e.clientY - offset.top
    }

    //show your div
  });

  $window.resize(function(){
       //reposition your div.
  });
```

I haven't tested it, but It might work if you click on the div, I don't know if the gmaps iframe will keep the click event.

Comment: Sorry I'm really newbie.. how can I know the mouse position at the place that I wanted to show the div ?